# Display data from promise firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-realtime-database, promise

I have a service like this

```
async getBirthdays() {
    const user = await this.authSP.getUserInfo();
    let bdays = [];
    return await new Promise<any>((resolve) => {
    this.angularFire.database.ref("birthdays").orderByChild("creator_user_id").equalTo(user.uid).once("value", (snapshot) => {
        snapshot.forEach(function (childSnapshot) {
          const value = childSnapshot.val();
          value.$key = childSnapshot.key;
          bdays.push(value);
        });
    });

    resolve(bdays);

    });
}
```

This promise return this array of objects

[image]

In my component i just try to display avatar value :

```
this.birthdays = await this.birthdaySP.getBirthdays().then(res => {
  var data = res.map(t=>t.avatar);
  console.log(data);
});
```

But *console.log(data)* return an empty array.

Any help is apreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right now you call `resolve(bdays)` before the `once()` callback has run, which means that `bdays` is just an empty array.

The call to `resolve()` needs to be inside the callback for `bdays` to contain the data:

```
async getBirthdays() {
    const user = await this.authSP.getUserInfo();
    let bdays = [];
    return await new Promise<any>((resolve) => {
        this.angularFire.database.ref("birthdays").orderByChild("creator_user_id").equalTo(user.uid).once("value", (snapshot) => {
            snapshot.forEach(function (childSnapshot) {
              const value = childSnapshot.val();
              value.$key = childSnapshot.key;
              bdays.push(value);
            });
            resolve(bdays);
        });    
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try the following:

```
this.birthdaySP.getBirthdays().then(res => {
  this.birthdays = res.map(t=>t.avatar);
});
```

Comment: Thanks. The pb was with the resolve outside the once